# Custom webpack configuration: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in 'D:\web development\react\webpack-react-boilerplate\src'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I have my custom webpack configuration for react, here is the link of my repository:
https://github.com/react-custom-projects/webpack-react-boilerplate

I'm trying to upgrade react and react-dom from **v17** to **v18** but after trying to update my index.jsx file from:

[image: From]

To:

[image: To]

I get the error of module not found (react-dom/client).
[image]

Here's the versions of react && react-dom in package.json:

[image: ```]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**:

The issue was that I’m using **@hot-loader/react-dom** && **react-hot-loader** which is not supported in react 18. React 18 supports **fast refresh** which is more efficient and used by create-react-app

Steps done to solve the issue:

- Package.json:

  a- Remove **@hot-loader/react-dom** && **react-hot-loader**

  b- Add **@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin** && **react-refresh**
- App.jsx:

  a- Remove hot loader
- Babel.config.js:

  a- Enable fast refresh in development:
  `...(!api.env('production') && ['react-refresh/babel']),`
- Webpack.dev.js:

  a- Enable hot reloading in devServer:
   `devServer: { //enable hot reloading hot: true,`

  b- Import react refresh plugin:
  `const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');`

  c- Add it in the plugins array:
  `plugins: [ // enables fast refresh new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(), ],`

  d- Remove alias for react dom hot loader:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
  },
},
```